# Webcam in Asus laptop not recognized

Tags: 11.10, webcam

my webcam in ASUS laptop does not recognise webcam. i installed cheese and say device not found
lsusb out put is:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0402:5603 ALi Corp. M5603 Video Camera Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 062a:0000 Creative Labs Optical mouse
```

any solution please

swadesh

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Going by the device ID this is a know bug and has been around for a while. Take a look at the [Launchpad Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/55567)  which has several links to other projects including this [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/m560x-driver/) one.

There is an Ubuntu Forums thread on the Sourceforge driver [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1629175)

Good Luck